# W3C equivalent for JavaScript DOMParser node.xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, w3c, domparser

I'm using `DOMParser` to parse some raw xml data loaded into a string. Given a particular `Node` object, I need to obtain the raw xml data for that node and everything beneath it in the tree.

For example, given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <elem>
        <div>this is some text</div>
    </elem>
</root>
```

...and given a node object representing the `<elem>` element, I need to obtain:

```
    "<elem>
        <div>this is some text</div>
    </elem>"
```

...as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3C provides [DOM Level 3 Load/Save spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-LS/) but I am not aware of any native implementation in browsers. However, you can use de factor standard component [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) to get the xml content out.